# Android appcompat-v7:21 error building gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i have downloaded the android API 21 sdk today and update the support library to 21, but whenever i try to build the project, gradle give this error message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       K:\android-sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I K:\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar -M K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.innov8tif.myapplication -0 apk --output-text-symbols K:\workspace\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
>   Error Code:
>       -1073741819

any idea if this is a bug in android 21 SDK or im doing something wrong.
im using android studio 0.8.11

Comment: Have you updated `compileSdkVersion` to `21` and `buildToolsVersion` to `21.0.1`?

Comment: i'm updating my sdk build tool to 21.0.1, i will try it and get back to you, if it works, please submit your comment as an answer so i accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @EgorN well, yeah that did it, please post it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti, check the accepted answer, as it did the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to update the `buildToolsVersion` to `21.0.1` and the `compileSdkVersion` to `21`. It's in the `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same build errors as described by the OP even when using build tools `21.0.1` or `21.0.2`.